# Dependency Issues between Microservices

Tags: microservices

There are about 10 microservices on the system but one of them has too much coupling with the others. Each microservices have their own databases. Lets say we have

```
LocationService 

ServiceA

ServiceB

ServiceC

...
```

ServiceA, ServiceB and ServiceC has some entity that is related to LocationService. It means that these services have some entity that has a field named which is LocationId referring to LocationDB with LocationService.

LocationService -> LocationDB

```
-- Location --

Id

Name
```

ServiceA -> ServiceADB

```
-- EntityA --

Id

LocationId

Name
```

ServiceB -> ServiceBDB

```
-- EntityB --

Id

LocationId

Name

Description

IpAddress
```

Any CRUD operations on EntityA or EntityB needs be validated with LocationAPI because ServiceA or ServiceB cannot validate the LocationId that is passed by the request. So when a client wants to create a EntityB by using ServiceB, the LocationId should be validated from somewhere else.

One way is to write a api composer and before any crud (actually only on create and update) operation occurs on EntityB or EntityA, it should send the LocationId parameter to the LocationAPI if it is validated then send it to the related API. But it becomes too complicated and microservices can be break easily with later changes because of the coupling.

Is there any other effective solutions for this problem or is this a design problem that boundries has been specified wrong

Answer (score 0):

There are cases when this happen, and you need to take a call on whose responsibility it is to ensure correctness of LocationId. 
If this api is being called directly from services you have no control on you can force the id by validating the location id on create and update. However if you have the control on services (are within your scope), you can expose location id as string, just a place holder for some id and it is responsibility of who is writing the data to pick the right value.

It boils down to how you expose your contract and who is the owner of the concerned data and what trust you have on the caller